# converting images to base64 and sending as json

Tags: java, android

I am trying to convert images i have to base64 then send them as part of a JSON string and all is going ok except when I have 2 images. What happens is i only get the 2nd image twice in the JSON and on the server side but Im failing to see why this is happening..

Here is my code:

```
JSONObject jsonPhotos = new JSONObject();
if (photos != null) {
    try {
        JSONArray jsonObj = new JSONArray(photos);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonObj.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = jsonObj.getJSONObject(i);
            String imageUrl = c.getString("url");

            System.out.println( "each urls: " + imageUrl );

            String cap = c.getString("caption");
            //get to base64
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageUrl);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 10, baos); //bm is the bitmap object   
            byte[] b = baos.toByteArray(); 
            String encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
            jsonPhotos.put( "imageData", encodedString);
            jsonPhotos.put( "caption", cap);

            claim.accumulate( "photos", jsonPhotos);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} else {
}
```

in my log each url is different. but when it gets put into the json the base64 encoded strings are the same.

Comment: because `jsonPhotos` is the same object, you overwrite its content in the second iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new jsonPhotos item on every iteration of the loop.
What's happening is that you create a single JSON object before the loop starts, and then you are continually updating it's "itemData" through every iteration of the loop.

I suspect that "claim.accumulate" is holding on to a reference of the JSONObject passed into it instead of making a deep copy.  This should fix it.

```
if (photos != null) {
    try {
        JSONArray jsonObj = new JSONArray(photos);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonObj.length(); i++) {

            ...

        JSONObject jsonPhotos = new JSONObject();  // add this line here

        jsonPhotos.put( "imageData", encodedString);
        jsonPhotos.put( "caption", cap);

        claim.accumulate( "photos", jsonPhotos);

    }
```